# Run a 3rd party Excel Add-in from VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-addins

I want to programatically run a 3rd party Add-in with VBA alone. Im using Excel 2010

Ideally, I'd like to be able to call the functions individually however I don't have any access to the code of the Add-in (it doesn't even appear as a password protected VBA Project it did in Excel 2003).

Hours of Googling has told me this was possible in earlier versions of Excel, either through `Application.CommandBars("Add-Ins").Controls("Custom Button").Execute` or   `CommandBars.ExecuteMso("Custom Button")` - AFAIK, the latter now only works with in-built functions.

This custom button also appears in the 'Right-Click' menu so could possibly be run with some sort of `SendKeys` implementation. This is however, clearly far from ideal.

I'm pulling my hair out over this - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which right-click menu does it appear in? Is it a COM add-in?

Comment: When I right click on a cell, the option to run the add-in appears at the bottom. It is a COM add-in.

Comment: Long shot but: `Application.Commandbars("Cell").Controls(Application.Commandbars("Cell").Controls.Count).Execute` *might* work.

Comment: You are amazing. It actually works! Can you explain why, just so I understand? Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I guess it's selecting the last option on the `Cell` menu. Is there any way I can select by name or label?

Comment: If that works, you should be able to use `Application.Commandbars("Cell").Controls("the button caption").Execute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how it has been added to the menu, this may work:

```
Application.Commandbars("Cell").Controls(Application.Commandbars("Cell").Contro‌​ls.Count).Execute
```

which simply executes the last control. Also this should work by the control caption:

```
Application.Commandbars("Cell").Controls("the button caption").Execute
```

Comment: The latter doesn't work -`Controls` will only accept an integer. I'm going to try and look up the label with `Controls(x).Caption`. Thanks again

Comment: Controls should accept the caption - what happens when you try it?

Comment: I returned the exact caption, passed that string and it works fine, Turns out it's prefixed with "&".

Comment: Yes, the & is used to underline a letter and make it the shortcut key.